# Field strength tensor in spherical coordinates

Tags: electromagnetism, coordinate-systems, differentiation, vector-fields

I'm getting confused by the change of coordinates when calculating the electromagnetic tensor in spherical coordinates. In particular I know that in cartesian coordinates:

$$F_{\mu \nu}=\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}.$$

If I suppose that the only non vanishing component of $A$ in spherical coordinates  is $A_{t}=f(r)$ (radial electric field), then how do I calculate the components (in spherical coordinates) of $F_{\mu \nu}$? I suppose the only non-vanishing ones would be $F_{tr}$ and $F_{rt}$, but I'm not sure on how to find them.

Answer (score 5):

You’re making the problem more difficult than it needs to be. The expression $F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$ holds in all coordinate systems, so in your example $F_{tr}=-f’$.

Any extra terms you have in mind would have to arise from raising or lowering indices with the metric. Doing so leads to non-trivial extra factors if the metric is not orthonormal, but as long as you keep both indices down, what you see is what you get.

---

> Because I believe that for the 4 divergence you have extra factors. For example I think that for $\nabla_\mu A^\mu$ in spherical coordinates, the $r$ term is $\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2 A^r\right)$. So now I'm confused on when these extra factors arise or not.

In the spherical coordinate basis $\{\partial_r,\partial_\theta,\partial_\phi\}$ associated to the coordinates $(r,\theta,\phi)$, the metric tensor is given by
$$g_{ij} = \pmatrix{1 &0&0\\0&r^2&0\\0&0&r^2\sin^2(\theta)}$$ and the Christoffel symbols (more specifically, the Christoffel symbols of the [second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols#Christoffel_symbols_of_the_second_kind_(symmetric_definition))) are given by

$$\Gamma^i_{jk} = \frac{1}{2}g^{i\alpha}\big(\partial_j g_{\alpha k} + \partial_k g_{\alpha j} - \partial_\alpha g_{ij}\big)$$
$$\Gamma^r_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}\partial_r g_{ij} =\pmatrix{0 &0&0 \\0&r&0\\0&0&r\sin(\theta)}$$
$$\Gamma^\theta_{ij} = \frac{1}{2r^2}\big(\partial_j g_{\theta k}+\partial_k g_{\theta j} - \partial_\theta g_{ij}\big)= \pmatrix{0&\frac{1}{r}&0\\\frac{1}{r}&0&0\\0&0&-\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}$$
$$\Gamma^\phi_{ij} = \frac{1}{2r^2\sin^2(\theta)}\big(\partial_j g_{\phi k}+\partial_k g_{\phi j}\big) = \pmatrix{0&0&\frac{1}{r}\\0&0&\cot(\theta)\\\frac{1}{r}&\cot(\theta)&0}$$

As a result, the covariant divergence of a vector field becomes

$$\nabla_\mu A^\mu = \partial_\mu A^\mu + \Gamma^\mu_{\mu \nu} A^\nu$$
$$= \underbrace{\partial_r A^r}_{\mu=r} + \underbrace{\partial_\theta A^\theta + \frac{1}{r}A^r}_{\mu=\theta}+\underbrace{\partial_\phi A^\phi + \frac{1}{r}A^r+\cot(\theta) A^\theta}_{\mu=\phi}$$
$$=\big(\partial_r A^r + \frac{2}{r}A^r\big) + \big(\partial_\theta A^\theta + \cot(\theta) A^\theta\big)+ \partial_\phi A^\phi$$

This can be conveniently re-expressed as
$$ \nabla_\mu A^\mu = \frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r\left(r^2 A^r\right) + \frac{1}{\sin(\theta)}\partial_\theta \big(\sin(\theta)A^\theta\big) + \partial_\phi A^\phi$$

This still doesn't quite match what you might find in a standard reference on [vector calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates). The reason is that in elementary vector calculus, we don't use the spherical *coordinate* basis $\{\partial_r,\partial_\theta,\partial_\phi\}$ but rather the spherical **orthonormal** basis $\{\hat r, \hat \theta,\hat \phi\}$, in which we rescale the basis vectors to normalize them.  Consulting the metric tensor written above, it's clear that
$$\hat r = \partial_r \qquad \hat \theta = \frac{1}{r}\partial_\theta \qquad \hat \phi = \frac{1}{r\sin(\theta)}\partial_\phi$$

Therefore, given a vector field $\mathbf A = \tilde A^r \hat r + \tilde A^\theta \hat \theta + \tilde A^\phi \hat \phi$ expressed in the **orthonormal** basis, its components in the **coordinate** basis are
$$A^r = \tilde A^r \qquad A^\theta = \frac{\tilde A^\theta}{r} \qquad A^\phi = \frac{\tilde A^\phi}{r \sin(\theta)}$$

And so we finally obtain

$$\mathrm{div}(\mathbf A) = \frac{1}{r^2} \partial_r \left(r^2 \tilde A^r\right) + \frac{1}{r\sin(\theta)}\partial_\theta\left(\sin(\theta) \tilde A^\theta\right) + \frac{1}{r\sin(\theta)}\partial_\phi \tilde A^\phi$$

---

On the other hand, the gradient of a scalar is a covector field:

$$\mathrm dV = \big(\partial_r V\big) \mathrm dr + \big(\partial_\theta V \big) \mathrm d\theta + \big(\partial_\phi V\big) \mathrm d\phi$$
This can be converted to a vector via the metric tensor, which yields the vector field
$$\mathrm{grad}(V) \equiv g^{ij}(\mathrm dV)_j = \big(\partial_r V\big) \partial_r + \left(\frac{1}{r^2} \partial_\theta V\right)\partial_\theta + \left(\frac{1}{r^2\sin^2(\theta)}\partial_\phi V\right)\partial_\phi$$
Finally, we make use of the orthogonal unit vectors to obtain
$$\mathrm{grad}(V) = \big(\partial_r V\big) \hat r + \left(\frac{1}{r} \partial_\theta V\right)\hat \theta+\left(\frac{1}{r\sin(\theta)}\partial_\phi V\right)\hat \phi$$

Comment: Great thanks! I'm wondering now, is it also true for Maxwell's equations $\nabla_{\mu}F^{\mu \nu}=0$? for example can I write the r component of the eq as $\partial_{\mu}F^{\mu r}-\Gamma_{\mu \alpha}^{\mu}F^{\alpha r}-\Gamma_{\mu \beta}^{r}F^{\mu \beta}$ where $\mu$ is given by the spherical coordinates (t,r,$\theta$, $\phi$)?

Comment: @Mathew Yes, that's right. Do you have a particular reason for thinking that's *not* the case?

Comment: Because I believe that for the 4 divergence you have extra factors. For example I think that for $\nabla_{\mu}A^{\mu}$ in spherical coordinates, the r term is $\frac{1}{r^{2}}\partial_{r}(r^{2}A_{r})$. So now I'm confused on when these extra factors arise or not.

Comment: @Mathew Those extra factors come from a combination of the Christoffel symbols and the fact that in elementary vector calculus, one typically refers to the *orthogonal* spherical basis rather than the spherical *coordinate* basis. I have expanded my answer considerably to clarify both points.

Answer (score 2):

In differential geometry partial derivatives form your basis vectors. You can express a vector as
$$A=A^\mu\partial_\mu.$$
To express $A_\mu$ in a different coordinate system you have to perform a change of basis. Let us denote $\partial_\mu$ for the Cartesian basis and $\tilde\partial _\mu$ for the radial basis. In differential geometry a change in basis can be calculated using the chain rule
$$\tilde\partial_\mu=\frac{\partial}{\partial\tilde x^\mu}=\frac{{\partial x^\nu}}{\partial\tilde x^\mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}$$
Likewise a vector transforms as
$$\tilde A^\mu=\frac{{\partial \tilde x^\mu}}{\partial\tilde x^\nu}A^\nu$$
and a covector as
$$\tilde A_\mu=\frac{{\partial x^\nu}}{\partial\tilde x^\mu}A_\nu$$
You are probably already familiar with these expressions but by explicitly stating them again we can get a transformation rule to obtain $\tilde F_{\mu\nu}$. Define ${T^\nu}_\mu=\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial\tilde x^\mu}$ for brevity.
\begin{align}
\\
\tilde F_{\mu\nu}&=\tilde\partial_\mu\tilde A_\nu-\tilde\partial_\nu\tilde A_\mu\\
&={T^\lambda}_\mu\partial_\lambda({T^\rho}_\nu A_\rho)-{T^\rho}_\nu\partial_\rho({T^\lambda}_\mu A_\lambda)\\
&={T^\lambda}_\mu{T^\rho}_\nu\partial_\lambda A_\rho-{T^\lambda}_\mu{T^\rho}_\nu\partial_\rho A_\lambda\\
&-\left[{T^\lambda}_\mu A_\rho\partial_\lambda({T^\rho}_\nu )-{T^\rho}_\nu A_\lambda\partial_\rho({T^\lambda}_\mu )\right]\\
&={T^\lambda}_\mu{T^\rho}_\nu F_{\lambda\rho}\\
&-\left[A_\lambda\tilde\partial_\mu({T^\lambda}_\nu )-A_\lambda\tilde\partial_\rho({T^\lambda}_\mu )\right]\\
&={T^\lambda}_\mu{T^\rho}_\nu F_{\lambda\rho}
\end{align}
The term in brackets vanishes which you can see if you expand it out again in partial derivatives. We see that $F_{\mu\nu}$ transforms like a tensor! (you are probably not surprised by this)

The point of all of this: if you know $\tilde A_\mu$ you can calculate $\tilde F_{\mu\nu}$ by just taking partials. If you know $F_{\mu\nu}$ you can apply the transformation law.

Comment: so if I understand correctly you are saying that $F_{rt}=\partial_{r} A_{t}- \partial_{t} A_{r}$. But wouldn't it be just a relabelling of cartesian coordinates? I was expecting some new factors when going to spherical coordinates.

Comment: @Mathew It has been a long time since I did these calculations but yes, $F_{rt}=\partial_rA_t-\partial_t A_r$. Because you have $A$ in spherical coordinates already you don't need to do much work. It is not just relabelling: for example the quantities $F_{xy}$ and $F_{\theta r}$ are in different bases and will generally be different. I tried to indicate that with tildes. But I agree that the formula looks suspiciously similar.

Comment: @Mathew I looked through my old GR homework and I found one that is basically identical to your problem. I found that $F_{rt}$ and $F_{tr}$ are the only non-zero components as well.

Comment: But if for $F_{rt}$ I don't get new factor, then why for example for $F_{\theta r}$ I might get new factors, and it's not just $\partial{\theta} A_{r}-\partial{r} A_{\theta}$?

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @AccidentalTaylorExpansion refers to the *coordinate components* of the  tensor.  These can have different unit-dimensions for different components: for example Volts per meter for the radial electric field and Volts per radian for one of the angular components. We often use "physical" components by expressing things in terms of a basis of unit vectors that are chosen so that all of the components of a tensor have the same units. This what one will see in introductor E&M books where formula for div, grad, and curl are given for spherical polas and so on. When we do this then there are indeed extra factors. In GR and in equations such as $F_{\mu\nu}= \partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu$  we   leave these out so as to make the equations simpler; the cost being that different components have different dimensions.